# Export class java in gwt

Tags: java, class, gwt, export

I created an application using Netbeans in java, with windows, i installed the gwt in netbeans and now i really want to export the class existing in java in gwt (especially windows). it is possible to do this?

Comment: please feel the difference GWT is "web toolkit"  and AWT is "window toolkit" .....

Answer (score 1):

If for Window you intend some swing class the answer is no, you have to rewrite it with GWT classes. GWT at compilation time is converted in javascript a thing that cannot be done with Swing.